# X11 session extends my two monitors display automatically (Debian)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, xorg, stretch

I'm using Debian 9. I have a laptop and a second monitor using an HDMI input. Whenever I start an application in a X11 session my screen display extends and I want my screen to mirror. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Before you do anything, you’re going to need to find out a bit about your monitors, like how your system is referencing them, their available resolutions, and their refresh rates etc. You can accomplish all of this with a simple command to query your monitors called [RandR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RandR).

```
$xrandr -q
```

Each heading is a listing for one of the ports on your graphics card. They’ll be something like `DisplayPort-0` or `HDMI-A-0`

Next to each one of those, you’ll see if it’s connected or disconnected and which one is listed as the primary connection.

The `--output` flag is necessary to specify which monitor you’re targeting.
The `--mode` flag tells it which resolution to use.
The `--rate` flag allows you to set your monitors refresh rate.

**Dual monitor** set-ups have some added flags that can be useful for positioning and priority.
The `--primary` flag specifies the primary monitor.
You can use the `--left-of`, `--right-of`, `--above`, `--below` and `--same-as another-output`  flags to set the position of your other monitors.
So in order to mirror your secondary monitor to your laptop you could execute this command.

```
xrandr --output DisplayPort-0 --primary --mode 1920x1080 --rate 144.00 --output HDMI-A-0 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 60.00 --same-as DisplayPort-0
```